# Different logo image for each frame in plotly for R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Let’s say I have this kind of data and I want to plot it using frames. I would also like to add to each frame a product photo, so it’s known how it looks. I’m trying to use logo solution, but that is static over all frames. Here in example see apple image at top left corner, I would like it to be different for each frame.

Do you know a way how to make it dynamic as frame changes?

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(product = c(rep("product_1", 10), 
                               rep("product_2", 10), 
                               rep("product_3", 10)),
                 size = c(rep(1:10, 3)),
                 scenario_1 = c(runif(30, 0, 1)), 
                 scenario_2 = c(runif(30, 0, 1)), 
                 scenario_3 = c(runif(30, 0, 1)))

cols_to_plot <- c("scenario_1", 
                  "scenario_2", 
                  "scenario_3")


plot <- plotly::plot_ly()

for(k in 1:length(cols_to_plot)) {
  data_k <- data.frame(scenario = data[[cols_to_plot[k]]],
                       size = data$size,
                       product = data$product) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(scenario = tidyr::replace_na(scenario, 0))

  plot <- plotly::add_trace(plot, 
                            y = ~scenario, 
                            x = ~size,
                            frame =~product,
                            data = data_k, 
                            type="scatter",
                            mode="lines",
                            name = cols_to_plot[k]) 
}

plot %>%
  plotly::animation_opts(1000,
                         easing = "elastic",
                         redraw = TRUE) %>%
  plotly::layout(
    title = paste(title), 
    images = list(
      source = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ0gg14eWlJdTfMs27Ec2JqnnE8lI4I40-XJ_1dQoxv498Oq_Nh",
      xref = "paper",
      yref = "paper",
      x= 0,
      y= 1,
      sizex = 0.2,
      sizey = 0.2,
      opacity = 0.8))
```